# Creating a "Rotate 90 degrees" button in MATLAB App Designer

Tags: matlab, user-interface, button, rotation

I'm trying to make a simple GUI with App Designer in MATLAB. I want to have a button called "Rotate 90" that will rotate 90 degrees the figure every time that is pressed. What I managed to do is to only rotate it once, but then I have the obvious problem that when pressed again, it will rotate the original picture again, instead of the new one just generated.

UIAXes is the axes where I previously showed a figure in.
I have the following properties before the callbacks:

```
% Properties that correspond to app components
properties (Access = public)
    UIFigure            matlab.ui.Figure
    OpenimageButton     matlab.ui.control.Button
    TextArea            matlab.ui.control.TextArea
    DropDownHistogram   matlab.ui.control.DropDown
    DropDownProperties  matlab.ui.control.DropDown
    Rotate90Button      matlab.ui.control.Button
    Rotate180Button     matlab.ui.control.Button
    UIAxes              matlab.ui.control.UIAxes
    UIAxes_2            matlab.ui.control.UIAxes
end


properties (Access = private)
    oldpath = addpath(genpath('/Libraries/')) % Load libraries
    ImageFile; % Image loaded
    handlehistogram;
    fullname;
    degrees;
end
```

The callback function is as following:

```
% Button pushed function: Rotate90Button
function Rotate90ButtonPushed(app, event)
    
    image90 = app.ImageFile;
    
    rotated90 = imrotate(image90, 90);
    imagesc(app.UIAxes, rotated90);  

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody's interested, that's how I solved it:

I added a property called rotatedImg

```
    properties (Access = private)
        oldpath = addpath(genpath('/Libraries/')) % Load libraries
        ImageFile; % Image loaded
        handlehistogram;
        fullname;
        filename;
        degrees;
        rotatedImg;
    end
```

and I wrote this in my callback function:

```
        % Button pushed function: Rotate90Button
        function Rotate90ButtonPushed(app, event)
         
            app.rotatedImg = imrotate(app.rotatedImg, 90);
          
            imagesc(app.UIAxes, app.rotatedImg);  

        end
```